# AIrflow suddenly stopped trigerring Dags

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Airflow version : 1.10.5

Airflow stopped running dags all of a sudden, i am using **LocalExecutor** , I have no idea why it stopped running,
I have around 50 files in airflow/dags directory.
some of them are at paused state, but those were there from the past 2 months.

```
# The number of task instances allowed to run concurrently by the scheduler
dag_concurrency = 60

# Are DAGs paused by default at creation
dags_are_paused_at_creation = True

# The maximum number of active DAG runs per DAG
max_active_runs_per_dag = 55
```

This is my config, also I am using postgresql as backend DB which was configured and was working perfectly fine until yesterday.
Also `airflow scheduler` and `airflow webserver` are running

but when I run `airflow scheduler` it gets stuck at this point.

````
[2020-04-24 05:18:47,898] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor                                                                                                                                ____________       _____________                                                                                                                                                                          
 ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __                                                                                                                                                          ____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /                                                                                                                                                          
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /                                                                                                                                                            _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/                                                                                                                                                            
[2020-04-24 05:18:48,219] {scheduler_job.py:1315} INFO - Starting the scheduler                                                                                                                             
[2020-04-24 05:18:48,220] {scheduler_job.py:1323} INFO - Running execute loop for -1 seconds                                                               
[2020-04-24 05:18:48,220] {scheduler_job.py:1324} INFO - Processing each file at most -1 times                                                                                                              
[2020-04-24 05:18:48,221] {scheduler_job.py:1327} INFO - Searching for files in /home/ubuntu/airflow/dags                                                                                                   
[2020-04-24 05:18:48,234] {scheduler_job.py:1329} INFO - There are 50 files in /home/ubuntu/airflow/dags                                                                                                    
[2020-04-24 05:18:48,320] {scheduler_job.py:1376} INFO - Resetting orphaned tasks for active dag runs                                                                   
[2020-04-24 05:18:48,347] {dag_processing.py:545} INFO - Launched DagFileProcessorManager with pid: 21557                                                                                                   
[2020-04-24 05:18:48,414] {settings.py:54} INFO - Configured default timezone <Timezone [UTC]>                                                                          
[2020-04-24 05:18:48,423] {settings.py:213} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=0, max_overflow=-1, pool_recycle=1800, pid=21557 ```
````

am I missing something here?

Comment: what does it mean, that it stopped running? Can you clarify it or post a screenshot of state? Any logs from the dags?

Comment: can you also add how do you launch Airflow? Is it docker installation?  What's your machine configuration (memory, cpu)?

Comment: consider I have two dags, one will run after the other one succeeds,
but Sometime It gets stuck at Queued state it does not go in running state.
if I kill airflow scheduler and restart it then it runs.

my cpu has 4 cores and 8GB Ram with 4GB of swap memory with linux 18.04.2 LTS..
also, its not docker install.. its a direct installation.

Comment: ```{scheduler_job.py:921} INFO - 1 tasks up for execution:
        <TaskInstance: dag.dag_load 2020-04-28 20:00:00+00:00 [scheduled]>
 {scheduler_job.py:953} INFO - Figuring out tasks to run in Pool(name=default_pool) with 128 open slots and 1 task instances ready to be queued```

this the log from the scheduler..